# Incorrect duration and bitrate in ffmpeg-encoded audio

Tags: android, audio, encoding, ffmpeg, aac

I am encoding raw data on Android using ffmpeg libraries. The native code reads the audio data from an external device and encodes it into AAC format in an mp4 container. I am finding that the audio data is successfully encoded (I can play it with Groove Music, my default Windows audio player). But the metadata, as reported by ffprobe, has an incorrect duration of 0.05 secs - it's actually several seconds long. Also the bitrate is reported wrongly as around 65kbps even though I specified 192kbps.

I've tried recordings of various durations but the result is always similar - the (very small) duration and bitrate. I've tried various other audio players such as Quicktime but they play only the first 0.05 secs or so of the audio.

I've removed error-checking from the following. The actual code checks every call and no problems are reported.

Initialisation:

```
void AudioWriter::initialise( const char *filePath )
{
    AVCodecID avCodecID = AVCodecID::AV_CODEC_ID_AAC;
    int bitRate = 192000;
    char *containerFormat = "mp4";
    int sampleRate = 48000;
    int nChannels = 2;

    mAvCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(avCodecID);
    mAvCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(mAvCodec);
    mAvCodecContext->codec_id = avCodecID;
    mAvCodecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
    mAvCodecContext->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    mAvCodecContext->bit_rate = bitRate;
    mAvCodecContext->sample_rate = sampleRate;
    mAvCodecContext->channels = nChannels; 
    mAvCodecContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;

    avcodec_open2( mAvCodecContext, mAvCodec, nullptr );

    mAvFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&mAvFormatContext, nullptr, containerFormat, nullptr);
    mAvFormatContext->audio_codec = mAvCodec;
    mAvFormatContext->audio_codec_id = avCodecID;
    mAvOutputStream = avformat_new_stream(mAvFormatContext, mAvCodec);
    avcodec_parameters_from_context(mAvOutputStream->codecpar, mAvCodecContext);
    if (!(mAvFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        avio_open(&mAvFormatContext->pb, filePath, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    }

    if ( mAvFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER )
    {
        mAvCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    avformat_write_header(mAvFormatContext, NULL);

    mAvAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    mAvAudioFrame->nb_samples = mAvCodecContext->frame_size;
    mAvAudioFrame->format = mAvCodecContext->sample_fmt;
    mAvAudioFrame->channel_layout = mAvCodecContext->channel_layout;

    av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, mAvCodecContext->channels, mAvCodecContext->frame_size,
                                                 mAvCodecContext->sample_fmt, 0);
    av_frame_get_buffer(mAvAudioFrame, 0);
    av_frame_make_writable(mAvAudioFrame);
    mAvPacket = av_packet_alloc();
  }
```

Encoding:

```
// SoundRecording is a custom class with the raw samples to be encoded
bool AudioWriter::encodeToContainer( SoundRecording *soundRecording )
{
    int ret;
    int frameCount = mAvCodecContext->frame_size;
    int nChannels = mAvCodecContext->channels;
    float *buf = new float[frameCount*nChannels];

    while ( soundRecording->hasReadableData() )
    {
        //Populate the frame
        int samplesRead = soundRecording->read( buf, frameCount*nChannels );
        // Planar data
        int nFrames = samplesRead/nChannels;
        for ( int i = 0; i < nFrames; ++i )
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < nChannels; ++c )
            {
                samples[c][i] = buf[nChannels*i +c];
            }
        }
        // Fill a gap at the end with silence
        if ( samplesRead < frameCount*nChannels )
        {
            for ( int i = samplesRead; i < frameCount*nChannels; ++i )
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < nChannels; ++c )
                {
                    samples[c][i] = 0.0;
                }
            }
        }

    encodeFrame( mAvAudioFrame ) )
    }

    finish();
 }

bool AudioWriter::encodeFrame( AVFrame *frame )
{
    //send the frame for encoding
    int ret;

    if ( frame != nullptr )
    {
        frame->pts = mAudFrameCounter++;
    }
    avcodec_send_frame(mAvCodecContext, frame );

    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(mAvCodecContext, mAvPacket);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
            if (ret < 0) {
             return false;
        }
        av_packet_rescale_ts(mAvPacket, mAvCodecContext->time_base, mAvOutputStream->time_base);
        mAvPacket->stream_index = mAvOutputStream->index;

        av_interleaved_write_frame(mAvFormatContext, mAvPacket);
         av_packet_unref(mAvPacket);
    }

    return true;
}

void AudioWriter::finish()
{
    // Flush by sending a null frame
    encodeFrame( nullptr );

    av_write_trailer(mAvFormatContext);
}
```

Since the resultant file contains the recorded music, the code to manipulate the audio data seems to be correct (unless I am overwriting other memory somehow).

The inaccurate duration and bitrate suggest that information concerning time is not being properly managed. I set the pts of the frames using a simple increasing integer. I'm unclear what the code that sets the timestamp and stream index achieves - and whether it's even necessary: I copied it from supposedly working code but I've seen other code without it.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp need to be correct. Set the time_base to 1/sample_rate and increment the timestamp by 1024 each frame. Note: 1024 is aac specific. If you change codecs, you need to change the frame size.

Comment: Thanks. Would that be the AvCodecContext's time_base? And the AVframe's pts?

Comment: I set the AvCodecContext's time_base, and the AVframe's pts, and it worked.